# Active JavaScript(jQuery) inside TinyMCE iframe window

Tags: javascript, tinymce

It has been hours already trying to find out if jQuery (or any javascript) can actually work inside the TinyMCE editor as it's the most powerful and customizable utility in its class. Search by search i understood what's the deal with `.tinymce({ cleanup: false, extended_valid_elements: 'script[type|src]' });`
but instead of CDATA sections around the code i now get  and still no success.
Is that possible or it's a restriction in order to prevent conflicts with TinyMCE interface.

Answer (score 1):

**Use this modal code to access element inside tinymce using jquery**

```
tinymce.activeEditor.$("#element_id").attr({'alt' : alternate , 'align' : align , 'title' : title});
```

Comment: This looks somehow wrong. Won't that fail with `tinymce.activeEditor.$("#element_id") is undefined`?